# Unity Unable to blend 2D Light renderers

Tags: unity, 2d, lighting

I've followed the documentation on Unity regarding 2D lighting. It said to turn on Alpha blending in the options. But this is how it turns out:
If Alpha blending is off:
[image: when off]

If Alpha blending is on:
[image: when on]

I'm not entirely sure why it's turning black. These are my settings for the 2D light:
[image: settings]

I've checked my layers, specifically the tile map floor, and it's on the Default layer.
[image: tile map settings]

I just want my lights to blend well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Apparently, 2D lights should have their intensity to be set at least `1` or higher. Otherwise, dark pixels will be drawn onto the 2D light renderer.

Comment: You may have global 2D light set at some intensity (presumably one) and that to make you confused.

Comment: um. the global 2D light wasn't the problem. My answer is the solution. Just need to wait for 11 more hours before I can accept my own answer haha